# Unable to call component method. Public method [storeLike] not found on component:

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Hello I'm trying to fix an issue I'm having with my livewire like component. I have a post-show component and a like component. In the post-show blade I have:

```
 <livewire:like :post="$post"/>
```

And inside this component:

```
<div class="w-full flex justify-center mt-3 text-white">
    <x-jet-action-message class="text-white" on="post-liked">
        {{ __('Liked') }} {{$post->title}}
    </x-jet-action-message>
    <x-jet-action-message class="text-white" on="post-unliked">
        {{ __('Unliked') }} {{$post->title}}
    </x-jet-action-message>
</div>

@if (!$post->likedBy(auth()->user()))
    <div class="mb-7 mt-4 text-center">
        <div class="block items-center">
            <x-jet-button wire:click.prevent="storeLike" class="bg-blue-500 px-8 py-3 ">Like</x-jet-button>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <div class="mb-7 mt-4 text-center">
        <div class="block items-center">        
            <x-jet-button wire:click.prevent="destroyLike"  class="bg-red-500 px-8 py-3" >Unlike</x-jet-button>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Now why does it say that the method is not found when it's there?

Comment: the method is declared in the blade, but you have to implement it in the component. Did you?

Comment: @Prospero Of course I have the logic in the component